# Is there any differences between developing Xamarin mobile apps on Windows 10 VS Windows server 2019?

Tags: windows, xamarin, windows-10, windows-server-2019

I am using Windows server 2019 and Visual studio 2019 for developing Mobile Apps using xamarin platform.
Is there any difference between using windows server 2019 and windows 10 for the above developing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you run android emulator in the windows server when you debug your application?

If you `useWindows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX)` as your Hardware acceleration for emulator
Run this command in the command line as administrator:

```
Dism /Online /Enable-Feature:HypervisorPlatform
```

to enable the Windows Hypervisor Platform on the windows 2019.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows

If you can debug in android emulator in windows server 2019, there is no difference between developing Xamarin mobile apps on Windows 10 VS Windows server 2019.